# SQL server import not using date format

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to import an excel file with column headers 1-1-2017, 2-1-2017, etc. But the wizard thinks they are 42736, 42767 - why is it treating them like numbers? Is there an easy fix?

EDIT: I closed the excel file (I had it open) and it fixed it. What's the deal with that?

Comment: you want your column names to be dates?

Comment: Not really but it's the way it was given to me and I don't know enough about excel to generate a new page that looks how I want it.